# Switch statement variation in C++/JS

Tags: javascript, c++, jsfiddle

Just learning JS , having a background in C++,C# , i tried this:

```
var userChoice=prompt("Enter 1,2 or 3");
switch(userChoice)
   {
       default : alert("Default case"); 
       case '1': alert("case 1 ");     
       case '2': alert("case 2 ");      
       case '3': alert("case 3 "); 


   }
```

and simillar snippet in c++:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int userChoice=1;
switch(userChoice)
   {
       default : cout<<"Default case "; 
       case '1': cout<<"case 1 ";     
       case '2': cout<<"case 2 ";      
       case '3': cout<<"case 3 "; 


   }
return 0;
}
```

While Executing both with userChoice=1 , i discovered that [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfFE8/) excludes Default case , while in C++ , [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Y5cCDo) prints all cases including default one. Ok let me summarise.

---

### JS :

1.Putting userChoice=1 , executes case 1,case 2, case 3.

2.Putting userChoice=2 , executes case 2, case 3.

3.Putting userChoice=3 , executes case 3.

4.Putting userChoice=4/5.. , executes default case ,case 1 ,case 2, case 3.

### C++ :

1.Putting userChoice= anything, it executes all cases!

---

Now a little change , I put a break after default case.
Leading to:

```
default : cout<<"Default case "; break;
```

What I observe is for JS , all the results are same except the default case. Instead of executing all cases , It terminates with default one, Well it Should ,because i have used 'Break'.

---

What is surprising is , in C++(after putting break ofcourse) :

1. No matter what value i give to userChoice , output is just Default Case. :|

---

Things that trouble me:

1. Are these expected behaviour of these languages , or they might differ on different compilers( for C++ ).
2. Does JS already knows the position( i dont know what word to use ) of the default case before executing , while C++ just follows down the code , till it reaches the break (or might be return or something else)?

And yes i know that i should be using break statements more.. but still .. out of curiousity!

Comment: With C++ you need to add the ``break;`` to break the switch at the end of each case. Otherwise it will execute all of the switches after the one the user inputs. I'm not familiar with JS so I can't help you with that.

Comment: ^^@PatrickEvans , i am doing it intentionally.

Comment: @Scott , So C++ states that in a switch , it will traverse all cases in downward direction , till it skips out of whole switch? So we need to consider placement of default case , if we arent using break. ?

Comment: Yes, you can think of ``break;`` as way to tell the compiler "Hey, I don't need this switch anymore, let's continue running rest of the program." The only reason you would want to not use ``break;`` is if (for the example) you wanted it to display all cases if the user picked 1. ``default:`` is used many times for control and error handling. But regardless I would stick to using ``break;`` at the end of each case if you are learning about switches so that you can get used to it. I'm not certain what you're trying to do with your program but there is probably a better way to write your switch.

Comment: @Scott , the problem was with using case '1' instead of case 1 . I was using character constants in switch statement , while userChoice was an Int type.
About the program , i wasnt making one , but was learning how switch actually works. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined variable `userChoice` as having type `int` and initialized it by 1.

In the switch statement there are character constants that will be converted to the type `int` So `'1'` will be equivalent to 49 if the coding is ASCII, '2' will be equal to 50 and so on.
So `userChoice` will be equal neither of the constants and the control will be passed to the label `default` and all statements after this label will be executed sequantially because there is no any jump statement

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int userChoice=1;
switch(userChoice)
   {
       default : cout<<"Default case "; 
       case '1': cout<<"case 1 ";     
       case '2': cout<<"case 2 ";      
       case '3': cout<<"case 3 "; 


   }
return 0;
}
```

If you would change the code the following way

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int userChoice=1;
switch(userChoice)
   {
       default : cout<<"Default case "; break; 
       case '1': cout<<"case 1 "; break;    
       case '2': cout<<"case 2 "; break;     
       case '3': cout<<"case 3 "; break;


   }
return 0;
}
```

then you would get output

```
Default case
```

If you will assign 49 that is the integer value of character '1' to userChoice then output will be

```
case 1
```

Comment: So i should be doing : case 1, instead of case '1' ?

Comment: @Abhinav Gauniyal  You are right. Or change the type of userChoice to char and assign for example '1' to it.

Comment: I did , worked! Thanks a lot! Could you modify the second code snippets , for case '1' to case 1. They might misled.:)